# How does Apple want us to set up our table view cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was told by someone helping me out with some code the other day that Apple wants developers to use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` for setting up the custom cells, instead of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I want to know if this is correct, and if so what are the benefits?

Comment: Like the biblical Apple, some methods are left in plain site to test the developer's will to resist using them. Don't eat the Apple.

Comment: lol.. Im guessing that means don't set the cells up where it tells you to in the template code..

Comment: I think that is incorrect, you should use tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just quoting the protocol reference:

> This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

What I get from this, is that it is encouraged to use this method only for styling the background / selected properties, but not the whole setup of the cell.

Comment: ahh, yes that sounds like a pretty good interpretation, thanks for that.. I'll leave this question open for a little longer to see if there are any other answers... if not ill mark yours. thanks.